# npn transistor as a switch

Tags: transistors

[image]

Actually 4.8 v dc is arduino nano output. In multi sim it works but practically not, transistor is 2n2222a npn.

Comment: google "low-side switch".

Comment: Part of your circuit is good and part is wrong. Hint: you have to shuffle battery, bulb and ground.

Comment: Also, the 1 milli-Ohm base resistor is a bit low... about 6 orders of magnitude. Not to mention that the voltage at the lamp would be 4.8V - Vbe (about 0.7 V).

Comment: What is your question? In addition to what @next-hack said, your transistor will also run very hot. You have wired it as an emitter follower. It is not configured as a switch.

Answer (score 3):

Your circuit is incorrect. And as pointed out in the comments the resistor is too small to bias the base. Here is the circuit you should be using

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0rfX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>
The resistor value can be calculated using the following formula.

> R1 = (V1-Vbe)/Ib, where Ib > Ilamp / Hfemin

Comment: You should correct the formula to: R1 =  (V1-Vbe)/Ib, where Ib > Ilamp / Hfemin.